# How does the inner function know about this parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

I'm learning Redux-Thunk and I have a question about JavaScript in general.

How do we get the dispatch function?

```
function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

Is it passed like incementAsync()(dispatch) or it comes from the outer function?

Code example is from https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: `var dispatch = incrementAsync();` now you can call inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The inner function receives the store methods `dispatch` and `getState` as parameters.

Your function will be used by library like `incementAsync()(dispatch, getState)`

You don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax `param => action` is for defining an anonymous function that takes one parameter and does some actions.

In your case:

```
var otherFunction = param => {
   console.log(param);
};

var fun = incrementAsync(); // is a function
fun(otherFunction);
```